# Проблема с подключаемыми библиотеками в простейшем TCP-клиенте

Tags: tcp-ip, сокет, c++

Начал учиться сетевому программированию для Windows на C++, скачал книгу "Эффективное программирование TCP/IP". Списал в Visual Studio 2008 первый пример TCP-клиента, а при компилировании вылетают ошибки, о том что подключенных библиотек нет. Может там какие-то устаревшие варианты библиотек? Исправьте, пожалуйста, на те библиотеки, которые будут правильными.

P.S. И ещё, посмотрите, пожалуйста, сам исходник. Если там есть ошибки, укажите на них, пожалуйста.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct sockaddr_in peer;
    int s;
    int rc;
    char buf[ 1 ];

    peer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    peer.sin_port = htons( 7500 );
    peer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAN, 0);
    if( s < 0 )
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    rc = connect(s, ( struct sockaddr *)&peer, sizeof( peer ) );
    if( rc )
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    rc = send(s, "1", 1, 0);
    if(rc < 0)
    {
        perror("Ошибка вызова send");
        exit(1);
    }

    rc  =recv(s, buf, 1, 0);
    if( rc <= 0)
        perror("Ошибка вызова recv");
    else
        printf("%c\n", buf[ 0 ]);
    exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Выложите исходник сюда для начала

Comment: И наконец, начните отмечать правильные ответы пользователей на ваши вопросы как правильные, делается это нажатием на галочку в сером крочке, под "пальцем вниз" слева от ответа.

Comment: Извините. Совсем забыл....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в проект библиотеку wsock32.lib. Проще всего указать ее в дополнительных опциях линкера.

**Дополнено.**

Открываем свойства проекта, идем по дереву Свойства конфигурации-Linker-Command Line. В поле Additional options пишем wsock32.lib. В программе не нужны инклюды

```
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

В функции socket поправить второй параметр SOCK_STREAM.

Альтернатива - добавить такую прагму где-нибудь сразу после инклюдов:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")
```

Comment: Ещё бы я знал, как это сделать.

Comment: Я вставил, вот как получилось:

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

int main( void )
{


Выдает во такие ошибки:
(9) : error C2065: pragma: необъявленный идентификатор
(9) : error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "comment"
(9) : error C2065: lib: необъявленный идентификатор
(10) : error C2144: синтаксическая ошибка: перед "sockaddr_in" требуется ";"
(9) : error C3861: comment: идентификатор не найден

Comment: Нужна решетка вначале. Это же директива линкеру. Никак не запомню, как тут писать код правильно.

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил, те ошибки исчезли, но есть ещё одна:

>`1>LIBCMTD.lib(wincrt0.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WinMain@16 в функции ___tmainCRTStartup`

Comment: Проект нужно было создавать как консольный, а не оконный.